# What's the difference between FIONBIO and FIOASYNC for socket?

Tags: c, asyncsocket

It seems both options can be used to make a socket nonblocking/asynchronous ?

Or what's the difference between nonblocking and asynchronous?

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't already, you can see the difference between non-blocking and blocking sockets on the [BSD sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets#Blocking_vs._non-blocking_mode) page on Wikipedia.

Also, you can look at the ioctlsocket() [MSDN page for a few details on FIONBIO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

[According to IBM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.basetechref/doc/basetrf1/ioctl32.htm):

> FIOASYNC  Enables a simple form of asynchronous I/O notification. This
>   command causes the kernel to send SIGIO signal to a process or a
>   process group when I/O is possible. Only sockets, ttys, and
>   pseudo-ttys implement this functionality.
>
> FIONBIO  Enables nonblocking I/O. The effect is similar to setting the
>   O_NONBLOCK flag with the fcntl subroutine. The third parameter to the
>   ioctl subroutine for this command is a pointer to an integer that
>   indicates whether nonblocking I/O is being enabled or disabled. A
>   value of 0 disables non-blocking I/O.

I hope this helps you out a bit.

Comment: When you say "set both options," what do you mean?  They perform two distinct actions.

Comment: IMO one uses either FIOASYNC or FIONBIO, since they do the same thing.You mentioned they do distinct actions, can you provide an example?

Comment: FIOASYNC sets/clears the O_ASYNC flag; The SIGPOLL signal is sent.
FIONBIO sets/clears the O_NONBLOCK flag.

Does that clear anything up?

Comment: http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-6-sect-4#chp-6-sect-4  <-- There's a useful explanation for you, to answer your last question about FIOASYNC.